# Building a list of strings with a regexp while loop

Tags: regular-expressions, search, string, list

I'd like to perform a regexp search, capture part of a matched string, and save
that part to a list. (Eventually the plan is to save this list to a file in a 
particular format, but for now a simple list will do.) I've tried the
following, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I `M-x eval-region` over the
whole document and `M-x first-words-in-numbered-list`.

```
(defun first-words-in-numbered-list ()
  "gets the first word in lines that start with numbered list and builds those
   words into a list, e.g. running the function on the following text:

   foo
   bar
   1. alpha zulu
   2. bravo tango
   quux schmucks
   3. charlie foxtrot
   10. kilo romeo

   should produce a list (\"kilo\" \"charlie\" \"bravo\" \"alpha\")"
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (setq first-words '())
  (while (re-search-forward
          "^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[.)]?[[:space:]]+\([[:word:]]\)"
          nil t)
    ;; for debugging
    (message (match-string 1))
    (sleep-for 2)
    ;; for actually storing the list
    (setq first-words (cons (match-string 1) first-words))))

(defun print-list-elements (list)
  "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own."
  (while list
    (print (car list))
    (setq list (cdr list))))
(print-list-elements first-words)

foo
bar
1. alpha
2. bravo
quux
3. charlie
10. kilo
```

Edit: I've updated the file to look like this:

```
(defun first-words-in-numbered-list ()
  "gets the first word in lines that start with numbered list and builds those
   words into a list, e.g. running the function on the following text:

   foo
   bar
   1. alpha zulu
   2. bravo tango
   quux schmucks
   3. charlie foxtrot
   10. kilo romeo

   should produce a list (\"kilo\" \"charlie\" \"bravo\" \"alpha\")"
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (setq first-words '())
  (while (re-search-forward
          "^[[:digit:]]+[.)]?[[:space:]]+\\([[:word:]]+\\)"
          nil t)
    (setq first-words (cons (match-string 1) first-words))))

foo
bar
1. alpha
2. bravo
quux
3. charlie
10. kilo
```

which is most of the way there! The problem is that when I `C-h v first-words <RET>`, I get the following:

```
first-words's value is (#("kilo" 0 4
   (fontified t))
 #("charlie" 0 7
   (fontified t))
 #("bravo" 0 5
   (fontified t))
 #("alpha" 0 5
   (fontified t)))


Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.

[back]
```

Why am I not getting plain strings like I wanted?

Comment: You have to escape backslashes in strings, hence your group should be `\\([[:word:]]+\\)`.

Comment: Use `match-string-no-properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with some general comments about the code below:

- Since your code will move point around, it might be a good idea to put the body inside `save-excursion` so the point will be at the same place where you started when you're finished.  But that depends on your application.
- Use `(goto-char (point-min))` instead of `1` (check documentation for reason).
- You can use a local `let`-bound variable to pass the list between your functions.  Setting and using `first-words` is not really necessary.
- As @mutbuerger already mentioned, you have to quote `\` in your regexp, hence the final part should look like `\\([[:word:]]+\\)`.  You can use the command <kbd>M-x re-builder RET</kbd> to test your regexps.
- As @politza said, use `match-string-no-properties` to get the results of last search without properties.

Putting it together, I would suggest something like this:

```lisp
(defun first-words-in-numbered-list ()
  "Gets the first word in lines that start with numbered list and
builds those words into a list, e.g. running the function on the
following text: ..."
  (interactive)
  (let (words)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward
              "^[[:digit:]]+[.)]?[[:space:]]+\\([[:word:]]+\\)"
              nil t)
        (push (match-string-no-properties 1) words)))
    words))

(defun print-list-elements (list)
  "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own."
  (while list
    (print (car list))
    (setq list (cdr list))))

(print-list-elements (first-words-in-numbered-list))
```

Comment: Please integrate the "*other comments above*" into your answer (perhaps crediting their authors). Comments can be removed at any time, in which case that reference to them will dangle.

Comment: @Drew - Thnx, done!